# Should I use iterator for a list which has only 2 items?

Tags: c++, qt, oop, iterator

I have written a small working demo to illustrate my question.

I have a complex model, which contains two sub-models (stored in a QList). My view could show either the first sub-model or the 2nd based on what user wants to see. For this reason I would need to keep track of the current/active/shown sub-model and I would need to be able to navigate to the other model when it needs to be shown (so need to track that one as well).

I can store current sub-model by its pointer like in my code below but it seems to me switching current sub-model could get complicated - specially if I need to add another sub-model.

Now it seems to me that iterator maybe the best way to keep track of current sub-model and `next()`, `hasNext()` and likewise `prev()` and `hasPrev()` will be seemless to call from UI but should I use iterator after all because I only have two items in the list (QList)?

Here is the code (please forgive public members, I wanted to keep it simple to illustrate my question)

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    MyModel model;

    // prints current selected model name for sake of simplicity
    model.m_currentModel->print(); // output is "No1"

    return a.exec();
}

class MyModel : public QStandardItemModel
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    MyModel()
    {
        subModels.append( m_currentModel = new SubModel("No1") );
        subModels.append( new SubModel("No2") );
    }

    QList< SubModel*> subModels;

    SubModel * m_currentModel;
};

class SubModel : public QStandardItemModel
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    SubModel(QString name);

    QString m_name;

    void print()
    {
        qDebug() << m_name;
    }

};
```

Please keep in mind (if it matters) that in my real project, the sub-model is selected for longer time and all operations that user perform are applied to that model. My application will only and always have these 2 sub-models.

Now should I keep track of current sub-model with an `iterator` or by `pointer` of the sub-model?

**Additional context info:**
My application is bit like car assembly line (but only two cars). First car comes on line (which is now the current car) and the application configures it to say premium package. Than the 2nd car comes in which is now the current car and it is configured as basic car. But user can go back and see what was configuration of previous car by selecting it as the current(=active) car.

Comment: Just choose a better representation.

Comment: You could keep three pointers: pointer to `SubModel` one, pointer to `SubModel` two, and pointer to the current `SubModel`. I don't see the need of managing two items with a list.

Comment: @Escualo but the issue I see with this is the `current` doesn't really know what that `submodel` is. For example if `current` is pointed to `submodel1`but I still try to get to `previous` model (which is of course NULL), it has no knowledge of that and handling this kind of scenarios can get over complicated. With `iterator`, it will be `hasPrev()` which will return NULL in this case so we know its the first `submodel`.

Comment: @Escualo this is true for 2 items, but the OP did elude to possible further items - but +1 if it is just for 2 items : )

Comment: `current` is always, well, current. It cannot be null because, presumably, you always have one `SubModel` selected (either `SubModel` one or `SubModel` two).

Answer (score 1):

You have at least three options:

1. A pointer - Store a pointer to the current item in use. This is light weight, efficient, but harder to use as you have no concept or "next" or "prev" etc...
2. An iterator - Iterators are designed to be used for STL (or Q-STLs) and are pointers on steriods... so you can do much more with them, I would say its a better option and does not cost you much more in resources.
3. A simple index e.g. `int activeCarId`. This is simple but very effective for lists, vectors, etc... since you can do `++` or `--`, the only thing you have to be careful of is the list limits which you can check any time like `if (activeCarId < list.size()) ...`

Personally in this instance I would keep track by using a simple index. For you the rule to swap is simple, you can do something like:

```
if (++activeCarId >= list.size())
    activeCarId = 0;
```

If activeCarId is 0 then it will become 1. If activeCarId is 1 it will become 2, but since 2 is >= list.size() it will be set to 0.

I am sure there are other options :)

Comment: Thanks, you spoke exactly to the concern I had in mind. I also had these options in my mind and thought the `activeCarIndex`could be most effective but than the list will have to be array, which is acceptable in this case. I am still interested if someone has something better in mind (like you said) but I did vote you +1 :)

Comment: @zar The list will not have to be an array it can still be a QList you simply use one of the two indexed accessor functions: `list.at(index)` which is read only IIRC or `list[index]` both will return `SubModel *` at QList index location : )